# what takes up the most of time in this small function? weird, and profiling breakdown given

Tags: c#

`blockProperty` is `dictionary<string,string[]>`

```
    bool BlockMatch(IList<string> container, string block, int cut)
    {
        string[] blockArray = blockProperty[block];
        int length = blockArray.Length - cut;
        if (length > container.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (blockArray[length - 1 - i] != container[container.Count - 1 - i])
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

Columns are: **inclusive Elapsed time**, **exclusive Elapsed time**, inclusive percentage (of the whole program), exclusive percentage, number of calls.

How can i optimize the method according to the profiling breakdown? As I find it strange that **the exclusive elapsed time of the method (6042) is more than a half of inclusive one (10095).**

Comment: originally I was expecting that the time taking from `string.inequality` would occupy 80% of the total running time of the method... apparently here it turned out merely 10%

Comment: did you try to take "container.Count" out of your for loop?

Comment: @deepee: i thought `icollection.count` is a property and is fast (O(1) of the icollection size). So I don't bother  cacheing it. Though what ever it is recorded by the profiler and the total time for it is 1503, i am content with that.

Comment: @colinfang: was this ever answered by someone or yourself? I would be happy to knwo the actual reason...

Answer (score 1):

To break this down any further, you may (for testing purposes) split up the function to small "one-line-subfunctions" so you can see the profiling broken down even more. Another help will be a double click on the profiling line to show you the individual function calls with their relative time.

Comment: The array isn't copied. I'll remove the downvote if you remove that bit.

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson: you are right, maybe I misexpressed myself, I cleaned this up.

Comment: Still, his question does say that the dictionary `TValue` is `string[]`, and the hotspot is in this method, and he doesn't use `ToArray()`.

Comment: oh, I overlooked that statement. in this case, I remove the first part of my answer and only keep the breakdown recommendation, the line-by-line discussions will go on at the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(!blockArray[length - 1 - i].Equals( container[container.Count - 1 - i]) )) {return false;}
```

Comment: Is Equals faster than != ? And if so, why?

Comment: i don't care about optimizing `string.inequality`, it is the mystic 6042 that cause my attention. if you say that `.equals` does help reduce the overheads contributed into 6042 then i will be grateful.

Comment: Even faster is `StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(a, b)` - ordinal comparisons are the fastest type of string compare you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that traversing the array in reverse-order is doing this: from what I know, arrays are optimized for forward/sequential access. Furthermore you might be preventing the JIT from doing bounds-checking elimination with all that arithmetic. Try this:

```
    for (int i = cut; i < blockArray.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (!StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(blockArray[i], container[i]))
            return false;
    }
```

However, in the end it depends on how many items you have in the array - if there are a lot there isn't much you can do (except use unsafe code, but that is only going to give you a tiny bit extra).

**Edit:** you can improve the speed of negative cases using HashCodes; at the cost of memory.

```
class StringAndHash
{
    public int HashCode;
    public string Value;

    public StringAndHash(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            HashCode = 0;
        else
            HashCode = StringComparer.Ordinal.GetHashCode(value.GetHashCode());
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(StringAndHash value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator StringAndHash(string value)
    {
        return new StringAndHash(value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var sah = obj as StringAndHash;
        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(sah, null))
        {
            return Equals(sah);
        }
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override bool Equals(StringAndHash obj)
    {
        return obj.HashCode == HashCode // This will improve perf in negative cases.
            && StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(obj.Value, Value);
    }
}

public Dictionary<string, StringAndHash[]> blockProperty;
bool BlockMatch(IList<StringAndHash> container, string block, int cut)
{
    var blockArray = blockProperty[block];
    var length = blockArray.Length - cut;
    if (length > container.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = cut; i < blockArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (blockArray[i].Equals(container[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```